# Empty Arrays, safe?

Tags: php

I'm learning how to create a shopping cart. ( From different posts/questions here on SO, I know that many will suggest that I just use a pre-fab system; however, as a newbie, I really want to learn how it works. Also, my cart will probably have more elements than the usual).

I'm using a for-loop to show the user-selected items in the cart session array. Ostensibly, only those selected appear on the browser; however, a var_dump, shows BLANK ARRAYS with NULL values are being created every time I refresh the page. Again, nothing is added to the echoed out cart view.

This may sound silly but I just want to make sure that those NULL ARRAYS will not cause any problems when the cart is passed for check out and contents are dumped to orders table in the database.

And what of the arrays with a product id but NO QUANTITY? Just thinking ahead if a smart*** user tries to add to cart with zero quantity.

Your knowledgeable opinions and experiences are much appreciated:)--KATY

Comment: Katy, this site is for asking code specific questions. We need to see some code and maybe some sample input/output to answer a question

Comment: This is all pretty much stuff that you should account for in your programming. Checking the validity of a cart entry (is the entry null, is the quantity >= 0)...etc.

Comment: The bottom line is that if values are showing up in your array that you do not intend to be there, you should find out how they are being populated and fix them.  They may not ever be problematic, but then again they may. Code that performs unexpectedly should be fixed through debugging.

Comment: They're only safe if you anticipate for them and program around them.  My general feeling is that your array should contain data you're interested in, and if NULL holds no interest, get rid of it.  Having a product ID with a quantity of zero is ok, as long as the transition to order handles it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the array is empty or not before using it?
You should probably also check that each element has a valid value before doing any database-operations or similar..

```
if( !empty( $array ) && count( $array ) > 0 )
{
    foreach( $array as $value )
    {
        if( empty( trim( $value ) ) ) // checks if 0, NULL or ''
        {
            continue;
        }

        // if you store product ID's in the array you can cast to intval
        $value = intval( $value );

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Johan!

DOWNVOTE?! I believe I asked a legitimate question.  I really want to learn.I believe it can be constructive especially for those that might have the same experience as I do. I thought that's what this site was for. I'm not even trying to cheat and ask for code.

So thanks again, Johan! :)